# The server at "server.localhost" can't be found because the DNS look-up failed.

Tags: apache, dns, ubuntu-14.04, virtualhost

I'm trying to run a local site, `http://server.localhost`, but am encountering the error in Chrome (similar issues in FF, Opera):

> The server at "server.localhost" can't be found because the DNS look-up failed.

My `/etc/hosts` file has:

```
127.0.0.1       server.localhost
```

And my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/server.conf` file has:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin steven@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/server
    ServerName server.localhost
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "localhost" 
    ErrorLog /var/www/server/tmp/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/server/tmp/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The directories `/var/www/server` and `/var/www/server/tmp/logs/` exist and are readable.

Apache config test says the syntax is ok.  An Apache reload is successful.

There are no errors being generated in the Apache logs.

My network settings for DNS are: 192.168.1.1, 1.2.3.4, 8.8.8.8 (192.168.1.1 is my router), and my Search Domains are: 1.2.3.4, 8.8.8.8.

A ping of server.localhost shows the IP as 127.0.0.1 (which is correct).

Apache/2.4.7, Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to William I figured out the answer here.
It seems my `/etc/hosts` file was not being given the correct priority, so I changed the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to reflect more default values.

**Changed from:**

```
passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

**Changed to:**

```
passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:          dns [!UNAVAIL=return] files
networks:       nis [NOTFOUND=return] files
ethers:         nis [NOTFOUND=return] files
protocols:      nis [NOTFOUND=return] files
rpc:            nis [NOTFOUND=return] files
services:       nis [NOTFOUND=return] files

netgroup:       nis
```

**Then restart the whole machine.**

Answer (score 1):

Firstly check your

```
/etc/resolv.conf
```

Since this affects DNS resolution.

Secondly, check all your browsers configuration. They generally all have proxy settings that you can amend to affect DNS resolution (in Chrome it is under advanced settings).

Comment: Good suggestions, but unfortunately these didn't work.  They contain:
    ``nameserver 8.8.8.8``
    ``nameserver 8.8.4.4``
Flushed DNS in Chrome and system, still nada.

Comment: Worse case scenario, you can install a DNS proxy on your local host (try dnsmasq) and proxy your browser through that.

Comment: Your answer led me to look at my /etc/nsswitch.conf file, and I changed it to reflect more default values, as it looked a little odd... I restarted my system and boom!  All working!  Thank you William, you led me in the right direction!

Comment: Glad to hear +1 due to your endeavours as well